# How to improve speed of the following code

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics

The following code do what I needed, but it takes too long.

```
 f[a_, b_, c_, p_] = 
  ProbabilityDistribution[(
   a b x^(b - 1) (1 - p) (1 + c a x^b)^(-(1/c) - 1))/(1 - 
     p (1 + c a x^b)^(-(1/c)))^2, {x, 0, ∞}, 
   Assumptions -> 0 < p < 1 && a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0];
data = RandomVariate[Evaluate@f[1.1, 2, 3, 0.5], 25];
pars = FindDistributionParameters[data, f[a, b, c, p]]
ll[a_, b_, c_, p_] = LogLikelihood[f[a, b, c, p], data] /. pars
h = DistributionFitTest[data, f[a, b, c, p], "HypothesisTestData"] /. pars;
h["TestDataTable", All]
Plot[{CDF[f[a, b, c, p], x] /. pars, 
  CDF[EmpiricalDistribution[data], x]}, {x, Min[data], Max[data]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Dashed, DotDashed}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Fitted", "Empirical"}, Exclusions -> None, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

Kindly help me to reduce the time of the code.

Comment: Have you timed segments to see where it is slow? Also, how long is "too long". Try `AbsoluteTiming`, the first step in speeding up any code is to identify where it is slowest.

Comment: At DistributionFitTest and then at Plot. "too long" time is in hours I am using version 10 on i7 fourth edition

Comment: You probably should not run `EmpiricalDistribution[data]` inside the `Plot`, because it has to be evaluated for every `x` again. Also, you could try to reduce the number of computations in `Plot` via the `Mesh` option. Further, you should reduce your example to a shorter computation time and then try to optimize it.

Comment: What do you want to do with `ll[a_, b_, c_, p_] = LogLikelihood[f[a, b, c, p], data] /. pars` ? It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I played around with your code a bit and sometimes I get an error that the algorithm `FindDistributionParameters` does not converge. Is this to be expected? Also those parameters vary wildly. Is this intended?

Comment: @rhermans I want to repeat this code several time and pick the output which gives me the maximum of the likelihood that's why I attentively add this.

Comment: @Berg Yes some time algorithm does not converge for 500 iteration. We have to avoid that. Parameter vary widely because sample size is small.

Answer (score 6):

OK, a partial answer without considering `h["TestDataTable",All]`: In the plot it is much faster to move the `pars` inside `CDF`. (Computing `CDF` numerically vs. symbolically, I guess.)

```
AbsoluteTiming[d1 = CDF[f[a, b, c, p] /. pars, x];]
(* <1s *)
AbsoluteTiming[d2 = CDF[f[a, b, c, p], x] /. pars;]
(* 14s *)
```

And it is faster to first compute the functions that are to be plotted and then hand those to `Plot`.

```
AbsoluteTiming[Plot[d1,{x,0,10}]]
(* 0 *)
AbsoluteTiming[Plot[CDF[f[a,b,c,p]/.pars,x],{x,0,10}]]
(* 2.3 s *)
```

Combine both to get the plot in about one second:

```
fct = {CDF[f[a, b, c, p] /. pars, x], CDF[EmpiricalDistribution[data], x]}
Plot[fct, {x, Min[data], Max[data]}, 
          PlotStyle -> {Dashed, DotDashed},
          PlotLegends -> {"Fitted", "Empirical"},
          Exclusions -> None, 
          AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```